# InvalidArgument when Invoking Expression containing get-date

Tags: powershell

Whenever i try to invoke the following String

```
$log = "Get-EventLog -LogName " + $name + " -EntryType Error -After " + $datum + " | Format-List -Property TimeWritten,Message"
```

i get an error

```
+ ... gName Application -EntryType Error -After 03/08/2021 11:51:37 | Forma ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-EventLog], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

The $datum variable is filled like this

```
$datum = $((get-date).AddDays(-10))
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. I didn't get any InvalidArgument exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, `$datum` expands to a string with a space in between the date and time parts - you need to add quotes around it.

Instead of showing you how to quote it, I'm gonna show you a better way:
Use *[splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)* instead of `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$logParams = @{
  LogName = $name 
  EntryType = 'Error' 
  After = $datum 
}

Get-EventLog @logParams |Format-List -Property TimeWritten,Message
```

Now we don't need to worry about quoting or qualifying parameter argument values, PowerShell binds them correctly for us.